# How to cite whole books in footnotes without adding the total number of pages (\autocite / philosophy-verbose)?

Tags: biblatex

This is my first ever question here, so please bear with me.

I'd like to cite a whole book in a footnote without a reference to a specific page. However, when I use the `\autocite` command without referencing a specific page it just prints the total number of pages in the book and I think it looks misleading.

How it looks with a hypothetical text:

> Jury, Rideon, *Descriptive Pool Studies*, Gullivers Publishing, Philadelphia 1995, p. 311.

The book is 311 pages long, so if I cite it like this it would look like readers have to check page 311 for something, whereas I'd just like to cite the whole book as a reference text for further study.

How I'd like it to look:

> Jury, Rideon, *Descriptive Pool Studies*, Gullivers Publishing, Philadelphia 1995.

Here's what my style looks like:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-verbose,
citepages=omit,
citereset=chapter,
singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
```

Anyone has a clue how to do it?

EDIT with my bib entry:

```
address = {Philadelphia},
author = {Rideon, Jury},
keywords = {minor},
pages = {311},
publisher = {Gullivers Publishing},
title = {{Descriptive Pool Studies}},
year = {1995}
```

Comment: Aaaand how does the entry in your bib file look like?

Comment: If you are getting `p. 311` then your `.bib` file is incorrect, since this means that the `.bib` file contains a `pages` field. The total number of pages should be in the `pagetotal` field.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.se! It's usually very helpful to include a compilable minimal document with your question, and for bibliography questions, a sample `.bib` item. My answer provides a good model for what a future question might look like.

Comment: I've added the bib entry and indeed you're right, there is a `pages` field!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting suggests that the relevant `.bib` items contain a `pages` field, which is incorrect for the total number of pages for a book. Assuming you still want the total pages as a potential field to be used, then you should modify those `.bib` items to use the `pagetotal` field instead. Alternatively, if you don't need the field at all, just remove it from your `.bib` file.  I think very few styles require a total page count for books, and I suspect that the fields are added to `.bib` items you find from online sources, which are notoriously unreliable.

Independently of this fact, however, it's easy to suppress the fields. In the example code that follows I've put both a `pages` (incorrect) and a `pagetotal` (correct) field in the sample `.bib` item, along with the relevant code to suppress both.

### Clear field solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
%%%% the pages field is INCORRECT in this type of bib item %%%%
%%%% it's included for demonstration purposes only %%%%
@book{Rizzi1990,
    address = {Cambridge: Mass.},
    author = {Luigi Rizzi},
    publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    title = {Relativized Minimality},
    year = {1990},
    pagetotal = {147}, 
    pages = {147}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-verbose,
citepages=omit,
citereset=chapter,
singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pagetotal}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pagetotal}}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \ifentrytype{book}
        {\clearfield{pages}}%
        {}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{
\ifentrytype{book}
        {\clearfield{pages}}%
        {}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\autocite{Rizzi1990}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Source map solution

Alternatively you can remove the fields using `\DeclareSourcemap`. For this case, this is probably a better solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
%%%% the pages field is INCORRECT in this type of bib item %%%%
%%%% it's included for demonstration purposes only %%%%
@book{Rizzi1990,
    address = {Cambridge: Mass.},
    author = {Luigi Rizzi},
    publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    title = {Relativized Minimality},
    year = {1990},
    pagetotal = {147}, 
    pages = {147}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-verbose,
citepages=omit,
citereset=chapter,
singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
       \step[fieldset=pages, null]
       \step[fieldset=pagetotal,null]
    }
 }
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\autocite{Rizzi1990}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote output]
[image: bibliography output]